# Restarting and debugging python application in virtual machine

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualbox, pydev

I use Windows host and Ubuntu guest with VirtualBox. Flask application sources are shared from host to guest using VirtualBox shared folders and my virtualenvs and nginx are on guest.

Now I should open SSH session to restart my Flask application (debugging with reload enabled, but in case of syntax error it needs a rerun) and I have no debug capabilities.

I used to use PyDev and Windows installation of Python with debug and restart right from IDE and miss this.

Comment: I think I don't really understand your issue... still, can't you just use Eclipse inside the virtualbox?

Comment: I have different projects inside different VMs and my VMs do not have GUI installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging you can use the remote debugger: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html (just point it to your main box IP and things should work).

Now, currently PyDev does not support launching a process through ssh, so, that'd be a new feature request (which you can request at: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev).

Comment: Remote debugger is quite good in PyDev. Now I'm evaluating remote interpreter in PyCharm: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html